# disable everything in update-motd.d dir in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

```
mitjab@server:/etc/update-motd.d$ dir
00-header  10-help-text  91-release-upgrade  98-fsck-at-reboot  99-footer
mitjab@server:/etc/update-motd.d$
```

i need to remove all auto updates or notifiers in my ubuntu server becouse it is to slow. How can i remove or disable it. Now when i login to server it takes 30s to see server when i write username and passwd.

How can i disable all this..

if i run

```
mitjab@server:/etc/update-motd.d$ update-motd --disable
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/usr/share/command-not-found'
```

Answer (score 13):

In the files `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd` cut out the string «session optional pam_motd.so»

Answer (score 10):

You can remove `execute` permission:

```
chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/*
```

Answer (score 3):

- There may be the `update-motd` package was installed with OS installation. You can remove whole package with this command: `apt-get remove --purge update-motd` in debian and derivatives. You must find out how to remove it from your OS if you don't using a debian derivative.
- If you think you did not install anything for motd or you culd not remove that you can check for `session optional pam_motd.so` line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/login`. Remove line from those files if exist in any.
- Or if you don't want remove anything, you can change files mode to 600 in `/etc/update-motd.d/*` folder. Folder path might be differs according to your distro.

Comment: mitjab@server:/etc/update-motd.d$ sudo apt-get remove --purge update-motd
[sudo] password for mitjab:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package update-motd is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: it is not installed yet

Answer (score 3):

use dpkg to list what has put things in your motd:

```
dpkg -S /etc/update-motd.d/
```

uninstall it with apt-get:

```
(for example)
sudo apt-get remove --purge update-manager-core
sudo apt-get remove --purge landscape-common
sudo apt-get remove --purge update-notifier-common
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that with recent versions. Actually, I wouldn't do that at all. Better to disable what you're not 100% positive you want to purge.